# Adding R-value (correlation) to scatter chart in Altair

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, correlation, altair

So I am playing around with the Cars dataset and am looking to add the R-value to a scatter chart. So I can use this code to produce a scatter chart using `transform_regression` to add a regression line which is great.

```
from vega_datasets import data
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

cars = data.cars()
chart = alt.Chart(cars).mark_circle().encode(
        alt.X('Miles_per_Gallon', scale=alt.Scale(domain=(5,50))),
        y='Weight_in_lbs'
)

chart + chart.transform_regression('Miles_per_Gallon','Weight_in_lbs').mark_line()
```

Here is the chart

[image]

Then I am looking get the R-value. So can use pandas with this code as I am not sure how to get the R-value with Altair.

```
corl = cars[['Miles_per_Gallon','Weight_in_lbs']].corr().iloc[0,1]
corl
```

Now I was wondering how would I go about adding the R-value on the chart as a sort of label?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by adding a text layer:

```
text = alt.Chart({'values':[{}]}).mark_text(
    align="left", baseline="top"
).encode(
    x=alt.value(5),  # pixels from left
    y=alt.value(5),  # pixels from top
    text=alt.value(f"r: {corl:.3f}"),
)

chart + text + chart.transform_regression('Miles_per_Gallon','Weight_in_lbs').mark_line()
```

[image]

In future versions of Altair, the empty data in the chart will no longer be required.

Comment: Thanks that worked. Yes, the df solution is not the most intuitive. I look forward to your datum solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that calculates the correlation using altair transforms:

```
def pearson(base, xname, yname):
    rbase = base.transform_filter(
        f'isValid(datum.{xname}) & isValid(datum.{yname})'
    ).transform_joinaggregate(
        mean_a = f"mean({xname})",
        mean_b = f"mean({yname})",
    ).transform_calculate(
        dif_a = f"(datum.{xname} - datum.mean_a) * (datum.{xname} - datum.mean_a)",
        dif_b = f"(datum.{yname} - datum.mean_b) * (datum.{yname} - datum.mean_b)",
        dif_ab = f"(datum.{xname} - datum.mean_a) * (datum.{yname} - datum.mean_b)",
    ).transform_aggregate(
        sum_a = f"sum(dif_a)",
        sum_b = f"sum(dif_b)",
        sum_ab = f"sum(dif_ab)",
    ).transform_calculate(
        r = f"datum.sum_ab / (sqrt(datum.sum_a) * sqrt(datum.sum_b))"
    )
    return rbase
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
from vega_datasets import data
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

cars = data.cars()
base = alt.Chart(cars)
pearson_r = pearson(base, "Weight_in_lbs", "Miles_per_Gallon")

chart = alt.Chart(cars).mark_circle().encode(
        x='Miles_per_Gallon',
        y='Weight_in_lbs'
)

text = pearson_r.mark_text(
    align="left", baseline="top"
).encode(
    x=alt.value(5),  # pixels from left
    y=alt.value(5),  # pixels from top
    text="r:Q",
)

chart + text
```