# Altair: Extract and display regression coefficients

Tags: python, altair

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60237871/altair-access-rsquared-value-in-a-regression) addresses how to access and display the R<sup>2</sup> value using `mark_text()`

I am interested in accessing and displaying the coefficients. Replacing `rSquared` with `coef` yields a flattened array of both the intercept and slope, as described in the [documentation](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/generated/core/altair.RegressionTransform.html#altair.RegressionTransform).

**How can I index into this array to display only one of the values, e.g. the slope?** I wondered if the `mark_text()` step should be preceded by a [transform](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/transform/index.html) (possibly `transform_filter()`, or if [`altair.Text()`](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/generated/core/altair.Text.html#altair.Text) could be used.

I am aware of [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61277181/adding-r-value-correlation-to-scatter-chart-in-altair) [approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65958756/how-to-add-prefix-to-rsquared-extracted-from-altair?noredirect=1&lq=1) which involve determining this information separately then adding it as an additional layer.

Apologies if this is a very straightforward question. Thanks in advance.

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)
x = np.linspace(0, 10)
y = x - 5 + np.random.randn(len(x))

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y})

chart = alt.Chart(df).mark_point().encode(
    x='x',
    y='y'
)
line = chart.transform_regression('x', 'y').mark_line()

params = alt.Chart(df).transform_regression(
    'x', 'y', params=True
).mark_text(align='left').encode(
    x=alt.value(20),  # pixels from left
    y=alt.value(20),  # pixels from top
    text='rSquared:N',

    # text='coef:N' # flattened array
    # text='coef[0]:N' # fails
)

chart + line + params
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can access this using a calculate transform:

```python
params = alt.Chart(df).transform_regression(
    'x', 'y', params=True
).transform_calculate(
    intercept='datum.coef[0]',
    slope='datum.coef[1]',
).mark_text(align='left').encode(
    x=alt.value(20),  # pixels from left
    y=alt.value(20),  # pixels from top
    text='intercept:N'
)

chart + line + params
```

[image]