# Annotate altair facet plots with metrics

Tags: python, annotations, facet, altair

I have the following code snippet to generate data and plot the scatters for two facet dimensions (`['train','test'], ['type_a','type_b']`) as columns and rows.

```py
import altair as alt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import pearsonr

np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randn(1000, 1), columns=['A'])
df['B'] = df['A'] + np.random.rand(1000)
df['subset'] = 'test'
df.loc[:500, 'subset'] = 'train'
df['type'] = 'type_a'
df.loc[300:700, 'type'] = 'type_b'

r = df.groupby(['subset', 'type']).apply(lambda x: pearsonr(x['A'], x['B'])[0])
r.name = 'correlation'
r = pd.DataFrame(r)
print(r)

alt.Chart(df).mark_point().encode(x='A', y='B', column='subset', row='type')
```

[image]
Now I want to annotate each facet subplot with the pearson's correlation as calculated using the groupby in pandas.
[image]

Is there any way to put this in the upper corner of each panel or even to the title (except for illustrator)?

Thanks!
Max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see how you can include a text annotation here [Altair: Extract and display regression coefficients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66604052/altair-extract-and-display-regression-coefficients). In your case the issue will be that you have two different dataframes and I *believe* that it is not possible to have two different frames layered in a facet (someone correct me if this is wrong). You could work around this by merging into one frame first:

```
import altair as alt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import pearsonr


np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randn(1000, 1), columns=['A'])
df['B'] = df['A'] + np.random.rand(1000)
df['subset'] = 'test'
df.loc[:500, 'subset'] = 'train'
df['type'] = 'type_a'
df.loc[300:700, 'type'] = 'type_b'

r = df.groupby(['subset', 'type']).apply(lambda x: pearsonr(x['A'], x['B'])[0])
r.name = 'correlation'
r = pd.DataFrame(r)

points = alt.Chart(df.merge(r.reset_index())).mark_point().encode(x='A', y='B')
text = points.mark_text(align='left').encode(
    x=alt.value(20),  # pixels from left
    y=alt.value(20),  # pixels from top
    text='mean(correlation):N'  # taking the mean to reduce to a single value
)

(text + points).facet(column='subset', row='type')
```

[image]

You could probably create a more complex string using `transform_calculate` with the vega expression strings https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/expressions/.